# Suppose $P(x)$ is a polynomial with $P(2)=2017$ and $P(5)=2002$. If it is given that $P(x)=0$ has exactly one integer root, find that root.

Tags: polynomials

> Question: Suppose $P(x)$ is a polynomial with $P(2)=2017$ and $P(5)=2002$. If it is given that $P(x)=0$ has exactly one integer root, find that root.

My approach: I tried solving the problem by considering that $P(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$ and that $$P(x)=a_nx^n+a_{n-1}x^{n-1}+\cdots+a_0.$$ Then $P(5)\equiv a_0 \pmod 5\implies 2002\equiv a_0 \pmod 5\implies a_0\equiv 2\pmod 5.$ Again, $P(2)\equiv a_0 \pmod 2 \implies 2017\equiv a_0 \pmod 2\implies a_0\equiv 1 \pmod 2.$ Thus, we have $$\begin{cases}a_0\equiv 1\pmod 2,\\a_0\equiv 2\pmod 5.\end{cases}$$ By solving the same we can conclude that $a_0\equiv 7 \pmod {10}.$

Also if $a$ is the only integer root of $P(x)$, then there exists $Q(x)\in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ with $\deg (Q(x))=n-1$ such that $$P(x)=(x-a)Q(x).$$ Thus, we have $$(2-a)Q(2)=2017,\text{ and }(5-a)Q(5)=2002=2\times 7\times 11\times 13.$$

After this I couldn't make any significant approach. I also understand that I shouldn't have made the assumption of $P(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$, but that's the best I could think of.

Can anyone help me progress (initially a small hint would be nice)?

Comment: Hint:  we have $(x-2)\,|\,(P(x)-2017)$ so, if $x_0$ is the root, $(x_0-2)\,|\,2017$.  And we get a similar result from knowing $P(5)=2002$.

Comment: Thanks @lulu. This approach directly helps in concluding the answer to be 3.

Comment: Yes...just list the divisors of each, add the right constant and look for a common element.

Comment: Just to settle the integrality question, note that $P(x)=\frac {14139 }{10}x - \frac {2027}{10}x^2$ satisfies your two conditions, and $P(0)=0$.  Indeed, this example was obtained by [interpolating](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Interpolating+polynomial+%7B0%2C0%7D%2C+%7B2%2C2017%7D%2C+%7B5%2C2002%7D) those three values .  We need $P(x)\in \mathbb Z[x]$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second approach is more fruitful. $2017$ is prime whence $2- a=1, -1, -2017, 2017$. If it is 2017 then $a=-2015$  and $a-5= -2020$, does not divide $2002$ , a contradiction. If it is $-2017$ the $a=2019, 5-a= - 2014$ , a contradiction. If $2-a=-1$, $a=3, 5-a=2$ is Ok. Finally if $2-a=1, a=1, 5-a=4,$ a contradiction. Answer $a=3$.

Comment: I may be wrong, but note that if $a=1$, then $5-a=4$ and we have $4|2002$, which is a contradiction yet again. Also, such arguments can be only made with the added assumption of $P(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[x]$, which is not given.

Comment: @SanketBiswas: I  have fixed my answer. Of course the polynomial should have integer coefficients otherwise the question does not make sense.

Comment: I guess you are correct. Otherwise the problem doesn't seem to be doable.

Comment: lulu comment also uses the fact that coeffs are integers.

Comment: Ya, I noticed the same a while ago. Thanks!